# A word or phrase to describe quick thinking in the moment

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Let me describe the situation where I want to use this word or phrase:

I was reading a particularly interesting book that I happened upon somewhere deep inside my university library. The book had a memorable epigraph. Unfortunately, I didn't have the **presence of mind** to take a photograph of the epigraph or write it down. I no longer remember the name of the book, and I have to find contentment in knowing I may never see it again.

Is "presence of mind" the right phrase? Perhaps I didn't have my "wits about me"? I wasn't quick thinking enough? Or something else?

I really want to capture the idea that I was engrossed in reading the book and wasn't really thinking about preserving the memory.

Comment: Single-word options include _extemporaneous_ and _impromptu_. _Extemporaneous_, in particular has connotations of mental agility because it is connected with [extemporaneous debate](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/faculty/dunnweb/debaterules.html).

Comment: Your title and post ask for two different things. Do you want a phrase for the ability to think quickly or **the lack of** said ability?

Comment: Another context of the OP is "present-mindedness."

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction It seems that he wants a phrase for the ability, so that he can say he didn't have it.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Yes. I could negate one into the other, so I suppose both may work.

Comment: @shuckles: `Thinking on your feet` is perfect for the former, but you can't negate it. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[On the spur of the moment](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/britannico/on-the-spur-of-the-moment) is a common expression used to say that a decision or an action is made suddenly,  without thinking too much about it, but

I understand that  the idea you want to express is that you forgot to take a picture because you were too absorbed in reading, so you could say:

- At that moment it [slipped my mind](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slip+one%27s+mind) to take a picture of the epigraph.

> - slip one's mind - pass out of one's memory

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Very simple word, but it fits your requirements quite well: **alert**

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alert)
>
> able to think clearly and to notice things
>
> watchful and prompt to meet danger or emergency
>
> quick to perceive and act

Or, since you need a noun for your sentence: **alertness**

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/alertness)
>
> the state of being constantly attentive and responsive to signs of opportunity, activity, or danger

Using this, your sentence becomes:

> Unfortunately, I didn't have the alertness to take a photograph of the epigraph or write it down.

Comment: _have the alertness_ sounds awkward to me, I'd say _wasn't alert enough_.

Answer (score 1):

Your title and post ask for two different things. Do you want a phrase for the ability to think quickly or the lack of said ability?

**Thinking on your feet** qualifies for the first one, I think, though I doubt it's used in negative sentences.

From [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/foot):

> React to events decisively, effectively, and without prior thought.

Answer (score 0):

As far as a single word request for "**quick thinking in the moment**,"

> ***[IMPROMPTU](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impromptu)*** *adjective*:
>
> **1**. Prompted by the occasion rather than being planned in advance: an *impromptu* party.
>
> **2**. Spoken, performed, **done**, or composed **with little or no preparation**. (Collins)

Extemporaneous *vs* Impromptu

Whereas “extemporaneous” can be rendered as "prepared in advance and carried out with few or no notes," “**impromptu” means "totally unprepared, performed on the spur of the moment**," a distinction that often goes unrecognized. See TFD [impromptu](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impromptu)

Comment: The first definition in _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) for _extemporaneous_, however, has two dissimilar parts: "**a :** composed, performed, or uttered on the spur of the moment: IMPROMPTU **b :** carefully prepared but delivered without notes or text." So depending on which sense of _extemporaneous_ a person has in mind, the word can imply exactly the distinction you describe in your answer, or it can be functionally interchangeable with _impromptu_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Unfortunately, I didn't have the ***[forethought](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forethought)*** to take a
>   photograph of the epigraph or write it down for later use. (M-W)